# What do you use to Profile SQL Server 2005 Express?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, sql-server-2005-express, sql-server-profiler

I've got a problem on an SQL Server 2005 Express instance, and I need to see exactly what is being run, since what *I believe* is being run works fine when I run it from Management Studio.

It appears that Profiler is not available for SQL Server 2005 Express.  When I attempt to run SQL Server 2000 Profiler against the 2005 Express edition, I get the following message : "To Connect to this server you must use SQL Server Management Studio or SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)."  However, in searching Express Management Studio for a menu to do something similar to what I need, I can't find anything.  I found a third party profiler knock off for Express, but prefer to not to install a client app on my customer's server.

How do you find out what is being run in SQL Server 2005 Express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [this](http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/) sql server profiler. Its free, its open-source.

Answer (score 2):

You can use xSQL Profiler from http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/Product/xSQL_Profiler.aspx
It's free for up to 2 instances.